# Can we set a value in ViewBag from the buisness layer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using mvc 3 ,I set the viewBag in Business Layer.I inherited the controller in buisness layer.But unfortunately the value in viewbag not getting in View. Is there any way for setting the viewbag in Business layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ViewBag` is primarily used to set data in the controller which is then passed down to the view.  I would not recommend trying to set `ViewBag` items in your business application, rather make a function that returns the data you want and assign it in the `Controller`.

You could do:

```
public ActionResult YourController() 
{
     ViewBag.YourItem = businessObject.YourFunction();
     return View();
}
```